Waiting for an element to appear in Selenium (WebDriverWait)
When we receive a list of elements in Selenium, with the "find_elements" command, we select an element from this list, for example element number 2 in the list
Example: driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'container bg-black-100')[2]
Now my question is if I want to write a command that waits for your element 2 to appear in the list which is my target how should I set up the following code!!
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'container bg-black-100')))


The locator expression you're looking for would be:
*WRONG
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'container bg-black-100')))[2]

*WRONG
Edit: The above locator is incorrect, as CLASS_NAME locators only work with single classnames. For multiple classnames and spaces, you can use XPATH:
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="container bg-black-100"]')))[2]

I'm leaving the wrong example here, to exemplify how easy it is to get mixed up between different Selenium locators.
Selenium has a reasonably decent documentation here.

Be careful waiting for just presence. Presence means the element is in the DOM, not that it's available to be interacted with. If you are going to interact with the element and want to wait for a collection of elements, you need to use EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(). There is no clickable equivalent that waits for multiple elements.

Actually... this answer is NOT correct. By.CLASS_NAME expects a single class name and you've passed it two. This will never find the element and will timeout . Instead convert it to a CSS selector, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.container.bg-black-100').

You are right @JeffC. Such locator will work with XPATH, but not with CLASS_NAME.  Will shortly amend my mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.
